# List of users showing the same information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am showing the subscription information for all users. The issue I have is that it is not displaying the correct information. It is showing the `current_user` subscription information for all the Users. When it should be displaying each users unique subscription information.

Admin views:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
|<%= @user.subscription.id %>|<%= @user.subscription.plan.name %>| <%= @user.subscription.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Admin controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @users = @user.present? ? User.where('id != ?',@user.id) : User.all

    render layout: 'new_application'    
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
  end
```

Error: `` NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the template should refer to `user`, not `@user`.

*Update*:

As @rlecaro2 mentioned, it's possible you've got some users with any subscriptions. In the case, calling `.subscription` on the `user` variables returns `nil` and you crash while asking for its `id`.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    <% if user.subscription %>
      |<%= user.subscription.id %>|<%= user.subscription.plan.name %>| <%= user.subscription.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Also since you're asking every user for its `subscription` and later on for the subscription's plan, you should explicitly load these to avoid unnecessary queries. For Rails 4, the `Admin` controller should look like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(subscription: :plan)
  @users = @users.where.not(id: current_user.id) if current_user

  render layout: 'new_application'
end
```

Note that it's not necessary to carry the `current_user` via `@user`. You can refer to it in the template directly.

Comment: I did that prior to posting. I was getting a `undefined methods` when I removed it.

Comment: @CorneliusWilson then you have something else wrong. You should use `user` as you've stated on `each` call: `@users.each do |user|`

Comment: Hm, could you include the piece of code that's assigning to the `@users` variable? Also paste the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Maybe you have some users that don't have a subscription?

Comment: Updated the answer as well.